# New Messages Doesn't Light Up Anymore

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, notification-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Envelope not working on my account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70323/envelope-not-working-on-my-account)

About a week ago, the new messages envelope stopped lighting up for me...even when I have new messages :(

If I click on the little envelope I do see the new responses under Most Recent Responses...but how come I don't get a notification anymore?

The bar at the top saying you have new answers stopped appearing at about the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70323/140548

Comment: I get neither the bar nor the envelope...is that also by design?

Comment: Per the other question I linked to, functionality is being moved into the inbox.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's the answer...